# Keep user’s privileges on accessing contents in JSON response

Tags: plugins, user-roles, api, json, rest-api

I use [WordPress REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) plugin to fetch WordPress stuff on a mobile app.

What Access manager plugin keeps the privileges on REST API responses?

I want restrict access to certain posts, categories etc for a particular role, So when the user of that role authenticates via HTTP request, could not access to that post.

**more details:**

> I tried some scenarios with the free version of [Advanced Access
>   Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) plugin to restrict a single post for a role; by ticking all
>   the options on the both Frontend and Backend lists but the post was
>   retrieved by the user of that particular role. The only way that the
>   post could not be accessed was when its status had been set to
>   private. But this way all the other roles couldn’t reach the post too.
>   Could AAM or any other similar plugin set the access level of items
>   (posts, categories…) globally in the system like what happens when a
>   post status is private? Apparently, this one certainly affects on JSON
>   API clients

---

I was told in The WP IRC to use `determine_current_user filter` in the `functions.php` of the active theme. So I added this code at the end of the `functions.php` of the current theme:

```
function no_valid_user_no_rest($user) {
    if (!$user) {
        add_filter('rest_enabled', '__return_false');
        add_filter('rest_jsonp_enabled', '__return_false');
    }
    return $user;
}
add_filter('determine_current_user', 'no_valid_user_no_rest', 50);
```

But the user got the whole restricted post via JSON output.

Regards